# Convert PHP array into html

Tags: php, html, arrays

I need to convert my PHP array in to html with some div class.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
if (!$con)
  {    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_select_db("asd", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM asd");
$something = array(); 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
$something[] = array("title"=>$row['title'], 
       "name"=>$row['name'], 
       "content"=>$row['content'],
       "image" => 
           array(
             "cls"=>"slide-image",
             "_src"=>$row['src'],
             "source"=>$row['source']                
             )   
       );
}
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

I want output like this

```
<div class="class1"> Here title goes</div>
Here name with some class
Here content with some class
```

Any help please ?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
   echo "{$row}";
}

i don't know whether it is correct or wrong..

Comment: you have to either print_r($row) or say which index of row you want. echo $row['id_column'];

Comment: You can't just say "it's not working".  Please go back and put your code in your original entry, and then tell us what it does, and what it doesn't do, so we know what "not working" means.  Don't make us guess.

Comment: Sorry, it shows just blank page when i tried that above code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","root") or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("asd") or die (mysql_error());

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM asd") or die (mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
       $title = $row['title']; 
       $name = $row['name'] ;
       $content = $row['content'];
       echo "<div class=title>" . $title . "</div>";
}
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: it shows div, but not that appropriate row value..

Comment: edit your question to reflect all of the code on your page

Comment: I updated the code in my answer try it out to see if you get a result

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in C:\xampp\htdocs\asd\index.php on line 36

Comment: try now I forgot to delete some commas and close the line

Comment: thanks for your time, but error.

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in C:\xampp\htdocs\asd\index.php on line 18

Comment: I updated again left off a double quote

Comment: yeah, its works.. but no need mysql_close($con).

Thank you very much @yamaha32088

Comment: Not a problem glad I could help make sure to select the check mark so question is marked as answered and please up vote this answer.